# PDFAnnotation in iOS <11.1

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit, pdfview, pdfpage

Creating and removing PDFAnnotation works perfectly fine on iOS 11.2, but have issues on lower iOS versions (don't know about 11.1, but test device has 11.0.5 installed).

PDFView after adding annotation to the page:
[image: PDFAnnotation after adding it to the page]

PDFView after removing annotation from the page:
(fine on iOS 11.2, on iOS 11.0.1 has issues)
[image: PDFAnnotation after removing it from the page]
Sample project can be found [here](https://github.com/xkampotx/pdfannotationdemo)

Maybe there is a way, how to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: I also observed this and wasn't able to find any fix. Did you? I suppose forcing iOS 11.2 isn't the end of the world.

Comment: @Oded, I don't work on that project anymore, but as far as i know the issue still exists there.